# How to use tkinter library in same time with pytube library to show progress of downloading in Label?

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube

Iam trying to show progress of downloading video in label using **on_progress** callback function, but it is only called at the end of progress or maybe called each time but didn't display the progress value. It only display the value of progress at the end of progress at 100%. I don't know where is the problem.

```
def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
    per = str(int(percentage_of_completion)) + " %"
    url_label.config(text=per, fg="green")


def download():
    url = entry.get()
    file = YouTube(url)
    file.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)
    file.register_on_complete_callback(on_complete(file))
    ready = file.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension="mp4", res="360p").first()
    ready.download()

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
entry = Entry(root, width=50)
entry.grid()
download_btn = Button(root, text="Download", width=12, bg="#3A3A3A",fg="white", command=download)
download_btn.grid()
url_label = Label(root, text="", font=("jost", 10))
url_label.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `url_label.update()` at the end of `on_progress()` function.

Comment: It's really works. thanks a lot